# Documentation for MBean attributes of a Datasource

Tags: java, database, datasource, pool

I want to monitor my datasources pools in order to fine tune my server using the resources that real day to day demand and take decisions in advance before it is  overwhelmed.

So I found this code that works perfect. It's a servlet that dumps information in a web when requested:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    writer.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    writer.println("<html>");
    writer.println("<body>");
    writer.println("<p><h1>Tomcat Pool</h1></p><p>");
    try {
        MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        Set<ObjectName> objectNames = server.queryNames(null, null);
        for (ObjectName name : objectNames) {
            MBeanInfo info = server.getMBeanInfo(name);
            if (name.toString().contains("type=DataSource")) {
                writer.println("--------------<br/>");
                for (MBeanAttributeInfo mf : info.getAttributes()) {
                    Object attributeValue = server.getAttribute(name,
                            mf.getName());
                    if (attributeValue != null) {
                        writer.println("" + mf.getName() + " : "
                                + attributeValue.toString() + "<br/>");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    writer.println("</p></body>");
    writer.println("</html>");
}
```

One request might look like this (I am just posting data for one datasource to simplify):

```
propagateInterruptState : false
useDisposableConnectionFacade : true
validationInterval : 30000
jmxEnabled : true
ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad : false
logAbandoned : false
commitOnReturn : false
password : Password not available as DataSource/JMX operation.
maxIdle : 10
testWhileIdle : false
removeAbandoned : false
minIdle : 10
abandonWhenPercentageFull : 0
maxWait : -1
active : 0
size : 5
logValidationErrors : false
driverClassName : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
name : Tomcat Connection Pool[2-2023938592]
poolSweeperEnabled : true
validationQueryTimeout : -1
numActive : 0
modelerType : org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
validationQuery : select 1
rollbackOnReturn : false
className : org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
numIdle : 5
alternateUsernameAllowed : false
suspectTimeout : 0
useEquals : true
removeAbandonedTimeout : 60
loginTimeout : 0
testOnConnect : false
idle : 5
initialSize : 5
defaultTransactionIsolation : -1
url : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SYSTEMLOGS
numTestsPerEvictionRun : 0
testOnBorrow : false
fairQueue : true
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis : 5000
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis : 60000
accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed : true
maxAge : 0
testOnReturn : false
useLock : false
waitCount : 0
maxActive : 120
username : root
```

That's what I wanted, I think.

The problem is I don't seem to find the doc where all this parameters are defined and explained to know what I am getting. "active" seems to be the actual number of request for that pool... or maybe "numActive"?

Any hint?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();` means that all parameters are already available over JMX, why not use traditional monitoring techniques such as `jconsole` or modern ones such as `zabbix` to view the runtime parametric information, why write code for this?

Comment: The idea is that my own code takes decisions and throws events in an automated way